# Intuition behind $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, proofs, intuition, number-theory

The result $$\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6},$$ tends to amaze young students because of its beauty.

However, although in literature there are many proofs of this result, I find that none is suitable for someone who didn't take some advanced classes in calculus. Moreover, *as far as I know*, they do not offer an *intuitive* explanation of why this result *should* be true.

So my question is:

> What is the key intuition -- that is, the picture --  behind the result? Are there any *visual* of anyway *intuitive* proofs (*) of the statement that can be used to convey a *better* (or, at least, different) understanding of it (to people who haven't taken advanced calculus yet)?

(*) Note that *full* rigour is not compulsory for the scope of this question (it is very appreciated by me personally, though).

Comment: This question was put on hold at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185020/intuition-behind-zeta2-frac-pi26

Comment: @StevenGubkin Indeed, I realized that it is not suitable for that site, but maybe it is for this one.

Comment: One of the things about intuition is that you can build it.  Part of what makes mathematics so beautiful is that you can take a result like this which you currently have no intuition for and custom build intuition to include it.  It does not have to fit into your old limited version of intuition.  Any of the proofs of this result could, with enough effort, become intuitive.  It seems like you are asking for an answer which would be intuitive to you currently.  But no one knows what you find intuitive.

Comment: How do explain to students that haven't learnt about series that $e^{i\pi}=-1$?

Comment: @StevenGubkin I see your point, but what I mean is: how can one possibly explain to some people who doesn't know about double integrals, Taylor, and complex analysis that the sum of the reciprocals of squares is somehow related to $\pi$?

Comment: @Alizter I have a good explanation for that one.  If you define $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x/n)^n$ (which I have a lot of good intuitive reasons to do), then $e^{i\theta} \approx (1+\frac{i\theta}{n})^n$.  But $1+\frac{i\theta}{n} \approx cos(\frac{\theta}{n})+i\sin(\frac{\theta}{n})$ by geometry.  Then by de Moivre, $e^{i\theta} \approx \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.  This approximation should get better and better as $n \to \infty$, so it is reasonable to conclude that $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: @Alizter  see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#mediaviewer/File:EulerFormulaAsLimit.gif

Comment: @Alizter BTW, if you define $e^x$ as I like to, as the solution to the diff EQ $y'=y$ with initial condition $y(0)=1$, then $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ is simply what you get by applying Euler's method to the interval $[0,x]$

Comment: @Alizter Sorry to continue this thread derailment, but I must also mention that $e^x = (e^\frac{x}{n})^n$.  For large values of $n$, by the tangent line approximation to $e^x$ at $x=0$, we have $e^\frac{x}{n} \approx 1+\frac{x}{n}$.  Thus $e^x \approx (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.  Proving that the error term here converges to 0 is a nice exercise with geometric series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably already know that $1/\zeta(2)$ is the probability of two "random" integers being relatively prime. Since this constant is related to number theory, you should expect any proof of the Basel formula to be hard work.

Probably the best proof from the point of view of transparency is obtained by evaluating
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$$
in two different ways; one gives $\zeta(2)$, and the other $\pi^2/6$. A version appears in

> Aigner, Martin; Ziegler, Günter (2009). Proofs from THE BOOK (4th ed.). Berlin, New York: Springer-Verlag. ISBN 978-3-642-00855-9.

But a shorter version appears in

> Apostol, Tom M., A proof that Euler missed: evaluating $\zeta (2)$ the easy way, The Mathematical Intelligencer, vol 5, #3, 1983, 59--60.

It has the advantage of pointing out that the second evaluation of the double integral is achieved via a very appealing (read tricky) change of variables; namely rotating the coordinate axes by $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 5):

Euler's original heuristic may "fly" with people who don't know about calculus: just as polynomials (e.g., with all real roots) are essentially products of linear factors $x-\alpha$ where $\alpha$ runs through the roots, one might imagine that $\sin \pi z$ (using radian measure) is a products of something like $1-{z\over n}$ for $n$ non-zero integer, and also a factor of $z$ for the zero at $0$. We can get the constant right by looking at the limit as $z\to 0$. Then it is plausible that the next-order term is the sum of inverses of roots... which would give the desired formula.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting

> What is the ... the picture...?

far too literally, an image of $1/\zeta(2)$ was included in the question,
"[What fraction of the integer lattice can be seen from the origin?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/151706/6094)"
The answer is 
$\frac{6}{\pi^2} \approx 0.6079$,
i.e., about 61%:

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any "intuition" behind it, it was mind-blowing when Euler came up with this ("What?! The reciprocals of **squares** give something belonging to the **circle**??", remember in Euler's time calculus was only really starting to untangle itself from geometry). And precisely because of that is that I consider this result of a strange beauty.